# Can I use the Facebook PHP SDK in Spotify apps?

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk, spotify

I need to be able to post information from my application to the user's timeline. Now, the only way I know how to do that is with the Facebook PHP SDK. The thing is, since I use the standard JavaScript way to connect with Facebook's login, when I try to get the user id with the PHP SDK, it says it's 0. Is there any way I can use the PHP SDK, or is there just no way to post to Facebook from a Spotify application?

Also, can I use the PHP SDK as well for logging in instead of the standard code that looks like this:

```
function facebook(){
    auth.authenticateWithFacebook('119914501490688', ['user_about_me', 'user_checkins'], {
        onSuccess : function(accessToken, ttl) {
            console.log("Success! Here's the access token: " + accessToken);
        },
        onFailure : function(error) {
            console.log("Authentication failed with error: " + error);
        },
        onComplete : function() {}
    });
}
```

Comment: did you add `*://*.facebook.com/*` to the list with allowed urls

Comment: Yes I got the "https://graph.facebook.com" added.

Comment: Do you got a website? otherwise you send your requests to there

Comment: Yes i do got my own website, I do all my php calls through there.

Comment: 1. did you add that to allowed urls (just to make sure)
2. why dont you use the facebook api through that?

Comment: yeah I added my own website to the RequiredPermissions, and that's what I am trying to do, I have the php SDK on my server and doing ajax calls to those files, just now getting them to work

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make sure that Spotify will allow access to the Facebook API endpoints by adding them to your app manifest file. See "Talking to the Outside World" in the tutorial at https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/tutorial/

Comment: yes and as I said before I added the  "graph.facebook.com" to the manifest.